# Access 2013 Report eats text when changing page

Tags: ms-access, report

I have created an Access 2013 report consisting of several Text fields all bolonging to one record. However when I open the report, in some cases a field is cut up over 2 pages, and some text is missing/lost between the pages.

Apparently i need a "reputation" to post images, and am totally new in here, so I dont have that, but I do have an image of the problem that I can send if there is another way to do this.

There must be somewhere I can set a property on the report, grouping or field or whereever, but I cant find the setting, and have tried a lot of things allready.

It would be ok, that the field is moved to the next page if it caannot be fitted into the current one, as long as the text within the field is not lost.

Hoping you can help me...
Best regards
Ingrid

Comment: If you can post your image to a publicly available URL, even temporarily, another higher-reputation user can insert it into your post.

Comment: thanks for the advice, will see how I can do that, dont really have a URL...

Comment: Do the text boxes run off the appropriate report width?

Comment: No, it is not a width problem at all (I know how to fix that). It happens when a text field falls within e.g. page 1 and page 2. I would expect Access to just move the entire field to page 2, if there is not enough space on page 1, but instead it shows top half of the text field, and 'eats' the rest' so information is missed.

Comment: I have heard som something you can install in top of standard Access, something called "developer extensions", or something like that. Do anywon know what that is, and if that might solve the problem ?